# Error bounds when unit testing floating point signal processing library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, floating-point, signal-processing

I have a signal processing library that functions to spec. However, I have identified some good places for refactoring. I have been meaning to incorporate unit testing into my workflow for some time and this looks like a good opportunity to experiment with non-trivial code. This is so I can test that the output is near-identical after refactoring.

I am experimenting with [catch](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/12/28/unit-testing-in-c-and-objective-c-just-got-easier.html) as a test framework, however, this detail might be irrelevant as (from what I can gather) all test frameworks hinge around results from operators, i.e.

```
REQUIRE(i_x == 2)
```

However, with floating point data, some form of error bounds checking is required . .

```
const float target = 2.000f;
const float tolerance = 0.000005f;
const float err = target*tolerance;
REQUIRE( (f_x > target-err) && (f_x < target+err) )
```

This would quickly get ugly for every test written, so I could, of course, make a (templatized) global function that returns a `bool` given `x`, `target`and `tolerance` as parameters.

Is this the way that everyone else does this? Is this best practice or am I missing a trick?

Comment: I'm not sure what best practices are, but that is what I've done... `isNear(float actual,float expected,float tolerance)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing is highly sensitive to context. The test you propose tests relative error. In essence you are asserting that, in this particular situation:

- Normal, acceptable code changes may produce deviations in each result that are small relative to the result.
- Bugs are likely to produce deviations that are not small relative to the result.

In general, I think the second assertion is often safe. “Random” code changes are likely to produce huge differences in at least some values. There could be applications, however, that work with floating-point in a fine way, in which case small deviations could cause results outside of specification. For example, suppose you have an arcsine routine that returns a result only slightly different from the correct result: It returns 1+2<sup>-23</sup> when the correct result is 1. Later, this result, x, is used in an expression such as `sqrt(1-x*x)`. This expression is real for all mathematically correct values of arcsine (for real inputs), but, given an x that is slightly larger than 1, it attempts to take the square root of a negative number, and an error occurs. So you have to decide whether the second assertion is suitable for your application.

The first assertion is more questionable. The sources of error in floating-point arithmetic are not always proportional to the final result. For example, consider taking the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of some input signal. For almost every output number, each input number contributes some portion. Some individual output numbers will be near zero, by happenstance. However, the errors in them may be proportional to large numbers in the input. So applying a test of relative error to such output numbers will produce false indications of bugs. Instead, it would be necessary to allow an error that is scaled in some way by the inputs.